# Only display images for WooCommerce orders with a specific status

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I'd like to only show images or text when a user has any WooCommerce order with status of "shipped" (this is a custom status I already have defined). My thought was to designate those items (the ones I want to show or hide) with a class and add php but I'm lost.

I have tried

```
function check_user_orders_status() {
    
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        
        $has_shipped_orders = wc_get_orders(array(
            'limit' => 1,
            'customer' => $user_id,
            'status' => 'shipped',
        ));

        
        return count($has_shipped_orders) > 0;
    }

    
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will add the order status in the body class on customer orders (order view), on order received and order pay pages.

The order status will be outputted as *"status-" + the current order status*, like:

- `status-processing` for a "processing" order status,
- `status-shipped` for a "shipped" order status,
- … *and so on* …

So you will be able to add some CSS targeting specific order status for specific elements to show or hide, like:

```css
.status-shipped .element-to-target {
    display:none;
}
```

The code:

```php
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_order_status_to_body_class' );
function add_order_status_to_body_class( $classes ){
    global $wp;

    foreach ( array('view-order', 'order-received', 'order-pay') as $endpoint ) {
        if ( is_wc_endpoint_url($endpoint) && isset($wp->query_vars[$endpoint]) ) {
            $order_id    = intval($wp->query_vars[$endpoint]); // The order ID
            $order       = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // The WC_Order object
            $classes[] = 'status-' . $order->get_status();
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you, so it is not possible to have this work on separate (not order received or order pay) pages? The idea was a completely different page which would show a photo when the user has any orders that are currently status "shipped", but if no orders have that status the image would not show.

Comment: @ShanePrice Your question is unclear, and the code you provided not really related to your request. Where exactly do you want that image to be displayed for this custom status? is it on customer My Account "view order" after order details or on a specific email notification? Also could you please add in your question an html example of that content (image) to be displayed for that specific order status?

Comment: On the homepage I wanted to show an image of a courier package if the logged in user had any orders that had a status of shipped. I am using Elementor page builder for this project where you can enter css classes in any of the widgets (image, heading, etc). So if the code defined a class that only displayed when there was a status of shipped, I could use that class in the widgets. Thank you for all your help

Comment: @ShanePrice On a "different page" (related to your 1st comment) you need at least to be able to get the order ID to get the order status and then set a custom class… I don't know how to implement that in/with Elementor... Elementor is not recommended with WooCommerce, as it is heavy and slows down everything.

Comment: I can create the page with the default block editor , Elementor is not a necessity. If we have any orders with a status of shipped I'd like to be able to hide a paragraph or image on a page other than a default woocommerce page..

Comment: As said, you need at least to be able to get the order ID (or to define the order ID you are using) to get the order status and then set a custom class… Using blocks will not solve your need more than using Elementor… There is nothing more that I can do or tell about for now.